# Can I force Objective-C to require prototypes in the interface file for every routine in the implementation file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm developing in iOS 6.1.

I'd like to setup Objective-C and Xcode so that for every method that appears in an implementation file, there has to be a prototype of that method explicitly listed in the corresponding interface file?

My problem is that I like to look in the interface file to see what methods I have in the implementation file and sometimes I have a routine in the implementation file that's not listed in the interface file.

Comment: Private methods should be kept private. If you want to see what methods you have in an implementation, hit Ctrl+6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very uncommon approach. Usually a class's implementation splits into *public* and *private* methods. Only the public part should be exposed in the header file as it's the only part that clients should use.

I'm pretty sure there's no way to make the compiler emit warnings for implemented messages that are not declared anywhere.

I you want to get an overview of all methods in an @implementation block you can use Xcode's method popup (above the code window, on the right).